# Wait for response from the Serial Port and then send next data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am reading data in bytes from `.bin` file and split the whole byte data into `16-16` bytes frames, so I want to 16 bytes frame one by one and wait until the first frame finished its cycle.

Callback method of SerialPort class:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    // Read data from serial port:
    byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
    serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> response = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        string currentByte = string.Format("{0:X2}", buffer[i]);
        response.Add(currentByte);

        sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", buffer[i]);
    }

    string responesCode = response[1].ToString();
    if (responesCode == "44")
    {
        // Wait until the first response is not received
        foreach (var packet in packetList.Skip(1))
        {
            // This method which sending the the data
            this.ReadByteDataFromFile(packet);
        }
    }
}
```

`FdBrowseFile_Click` button click:

```
private void FdBrowseFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

        foreach (byte[] copySlice in fileBytes.Slices(16))
        {
            var splitedByteArray = copySlice;
            if (splitedByteArray.Length != 16)
            {
                byte[] padd = new byte[16];
                var startAt = 0;
                Array.Copy(splitedByteArray, 0, padd, startAt, splitedByteArray.Length);
                packetList.Add(padd);
            }
            else
            {
                packetList.Add(splitedByteArray);
            }
        }
        ReadByteDataFromFile(packetList[0]);
    }
}
```

ReadByteDataFromFile method:

```
public void ReadByteDataFromFile(byte[] packet) {
 try {
  byte[] mBuffer = new byte[24];
  byte[] payload = new byte[16];
  int i = 0;
  foreach(var bytes in packet) {
   payload[i++] = bytes;
  }
  CheckSumHelper checkSumHelper = new CheckSumHelper();
  var ckSum = checkSumHelper.GetCheckSum(payload);
  mBuffer[0] = 0x02;
  mBuffer[1] = 0x10;
  mBuffer[2] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[0]);
  mBuffer[3] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[1]);
  mBuffer[4] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[2]);
  mBuffer[5] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[3]);
  mBuffer[6] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[4]);
  mBuffer[7] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[5]);
  mBuffer[8] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[6]);
  mBuffer[9] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[7]);
  mBuffer[10] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[8]);
  mBuffer[11] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[9]);
  mBuffer[12] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[10]);
  mBuffer[13] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[11]);
  mBuffer[14] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[12]);
  mBuffer[15] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[13]);
  mBuffer[16] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[14]);
  mBuffer[17] = CheckSumHelper.GetBytesFromDecimal(packet[15]);
  mBuffer[18] = 0x17;
  mBuffer[19] = 0x00;
  mBuffer[20] = 0x00;
  mBuffer[21] = 0x00;
  mBuffer[22] = Convert.ToByte(int.Parse(ckSum, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
  mBuffer[23] = 0x03;
  serialPort.Write(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler();
  exceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
 }
}
```

How I can add a delay for `ReadByteDataFromFile` method?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. From your code, it's unclear what your question is. What does not work? At which line? What do you want to achieve? Furthermore, your code is incomplete: e.g. missing `ReadByteDataFromFile` and `packetList`.

Comment: @dymanoid I want to send data to the serial port i.e to this method:`ReadByteDataFromFile`

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for the reply! I added the code

Comment: My advice would be to first write readable code and split things up. F.e. `payload` is only used to calculate the checksum, why even copy the data? Also there are better ways to copy data from one array to the other. Also, I'm pretty sure `GetBytesFromDecimal` has nothing to do with the checksum, or does it? Also, why do you need to parse the checksum, if it's a number, it should probably return an `int` instead of a `string`. Also, the method named `ReadByteDataFromFile` doesn't read any thing from a file...

Comment: @huysentruitw totally agreed with you!

Comment: Will do the first thing once got the time but there is nothing impacting the current execution

Comment: Please check the answer update regarding sync vs async API use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait in a loop for a full response after you write a first frame.

```
// Set read timeout to value recommended in the communication protocol specification 
// so serial port operations don't stuck.
_port.WriteTimeout = 200;
_port.ReadTimeout = 200;

public void OnClick()
{
    // Write first frame.
    _port.Write(...);
    // Now wait for the full response.

    // Expected response length. Look for the constant value from the device communication 
    // protocol specification or extract from the response header (first response bytes) if  
    // there is any specified in the protocol.
    int count = ...; 
    var buffer = new byte[count];
    var offset = 0;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        var readCount = _port.Read(buffer, offset, count);                 
        offset += readCount;
        count -= readCount;
    }
    // Now buffer contains full response or TimeoutException instance is thrown by SerialPort.
    // Check response status code and write other frames.
}
```

In order to not block UI thread you most probably still need to utilize synchronous API and `Task.Run()`. See [C# await event and timeout in serial port communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335736/c-sharp-await-event-and-timeout-in-serial-port-communication/53633030#53633030) discussion on StackOverflow.

For more information check [Top 5 SerialPort Tips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/) article by Kim Hamilton.

Comment: So actually i need to use that for loop after while? Or inside while?

Comment: What `for` loop? The `while` loop in my code snippet is required get a full response (some form of a frame acknowledgement) rather than a part of it from the device because `SerialPort.Read()` finish execution as soon as it receives any number of bytes.

Comment: That means i need to replace that forloop with the while

Answer (score 7):

What you need is a way to block the execution of some code, until something else has happened, or - how to get things running on two threads synchronously. 
.NET has quite a few classes in the `System.Threading` namespace for synchronization. We'll use `AutoResetEvent` here.

Think of `AutoResetEvent` as a turnstile.

[image: turnstile]

You can't move forward if the the person on the other side stops.
When you move forward, you call `Wait` - and it blocks you from moving, 
until someone calls `Set` on it.

Now if we apply that to our problem:
We need to stop sending data until we get an acceptable response.
So call `Wait` when sending data, and let the response handling code call `Set` to let it move forward.

Here's an example which simulates a modem.
You send some AT commands, it responds, but the responses always end with `\r\n`.

```
var port = new SerialPort("COM2");
port.Open();

var mre = new AutoResetEvent(false);
var buffer = new StringBuilder();

port.DataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    buffer.Append(port.ReadExisting());
    if (buffer.ToString().IndexOf("\r\n") >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got response: {0}", buffer);

        mre.Set(); //allow loop to continue
        buffer.Clear();
    }
};


var commandsToSend = new string[] { "AT", "AT", "AT+CSQ" };
var responseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

foreach (var command in commandsToSend)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write '{0}' to {1}", command, port.PortName);
        port.WriteLine(command);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for response...");

        //this is where we block
        if (!mre.WaitOne(responseTimeout))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not receive response");
            //do something
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write took longer than expected");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to write to port");
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Sample output when tested through virtual serial port:
(I just reply with `OK<CR><LF>`)

```
Write 'AT' to COM2
Waiting for response...
Got response: OK

Write 'AT' to COM2
Waiting for response...
Got response: OK

Write 'AT+CSQ' to COM2
Waiting for response...
Did not receive response
```